# To find the sum of a series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I am stuck trying to find the sum of the series
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ne^{nx}}{1+n^2}    $$
for $|x|<\pi$. Any hints or direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: (And the answer... is [not very nice](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B%28-e%5Ex%29%5En%2F%281%2Bn%5E2%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+-Infinity%2C+Infinity%7D%5D).)

Comment: Don't just ask. Always show your attempt.